# Find the truth values for each P(x, y)???

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here is the problem

> Let $S$ denote the two-element set $\{0, 1\}$. Find truth values (i.e. True of False) for each of $P(0, 0)$, $P(0, 1)$, $P(1, 0)$, $P(1, 1)$ so that
>
> $\forall x\in S, \exists y \in S, P(x, y)$ is true
>
> But
>
> $\exists y \in S, \forall x\in S, P(x, y)$ is false.
>
> This exercises illustrates the fact that changing the order of your quantifiers can change the meaning of your statement.

The problem's hint:

> Just to clarify, for problem 5 you are assigning the value True or
> False to each of $P(0,0)$, $P(0,1)$, $P(1,0)$, and $P(1,1)$. That's four
> choices for you to make.
>
> For example, if you choose
>
> $P(0,0)=$True
>
> $P(0,1)=$True
>
> $P(1,0)=$True
>
> $P(1,1)=$True
>
> you'll see that both of the given statements become true, and if you
> choose
>
> $P(0,0)=$False
>
> $P(0,1)=$False
>
> $P(1,0)=$False
>
> $P(1,1)=$False
>
> you'll see that both of the given statements become false.
>
> What set of 4 choices makes the first given statement true and the
> second given statement false?

I answered the question like...

```
There are two pairs of truth values for P(0,0), P(0,1), P(1,0), P(1,1)
which satisfy two statements. (true true false false), (false false true true).
```

And the professor said "You just need to find one such assignment."

Um.. I'm totally lost here. Could anyone help me to solve this problem???

Comment: You have to change the order of quantifiers, to make the exercise meaningful.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out! I just edited the question :) I appreciate that

Comment: Ok the 4 cases for the first one. For the secon one you have to change it a little bit, e.g. P(0,0) False.

Comment: Um I don't get it. Could you explain on the answer??? YOu are saying I need to assume P(0, 0) is False??? I need full explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that, for each $x$, we pick one $y$ so that $P(x,y)$ is true (in order to keep the first statement true), but this *shouldn't be the same* $y$ for all values of $x$ (in order to keep the second statement false).

So, let's pick $y=0$ for $x=0$ and $y=1$ for $x=1$. (This is one possible example, there are others.) Now set:

$$P(0,0)=\top, P(1,1)=\top$$

but:

$$P(0,1)=\bot, P(1,0)=\bot$$

You can easily check that this choice of truth values does the job.

Comment: Um do you mean I need to experiment four different cases for this problem?

Comment: No, I gave you a solution, you just need to understand it.

Comment: I've just chosen for you $P(0,0)=true, P(0,1)=false,P(1,0)=false,P(1,1)=true$. Once you convince yourself that it *is* a solution, the problem is done.

Comment: @JohnBaek You can also pick the other way round: $y=1$ for $x=0$ and $y=0$ for $x=1$. This would give you $P(0,0)=false,P(0,1)=true,P(1,0)=true,P(1,1)=false$. This would be over the top of what your professor expects.